# phpmyadmin initial setup generating errors

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am trying to set up phpmyadmin on my machine and after the initial setup and the installation of xampp I am getting the errors below. I tried to troubleshoot this problem for quite a while by modifying the `config.inc.php` file with no success. I was wondering if anyone has encountered a similar problem and might be able to help me fix this problem?

[image]

**config.inc.php file**

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'HTTP';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'myusername';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to use advanced features, but phpmyadmin can't connect to mysql using specified user/password:

```
/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
```

Either use correct mysql user/password pair here, or comment out these lines if you don't want advanced features. Also, the database under `pmadb` (`phpmyadmin` by default) must also exist (the purpose of this database is to store phpmyadmin-specific data). If it doesn't, create it manually and ensure your mysql user has full access rights to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Commenting all the advanced features out worked for me however entering the correct username and password in the area mentioned above did not help. I appreciate the help:)